# How to save joint coordinates in a file in c#?

Tags: c#, coordinates, kinect-sdk

I am making a Kinect application that can detect the coordinates of the joints of the right arm; now I want to save this data of the coordinates in a file, either txt or csv, but I don't know how to do it, can anybody help me? I am using the Kinect SDK v1.8 in c#

Hope you can help me

Comment: Give more details and code example.

Comment: Have a look at `System.IO.File.CreateText`. That should get you started.

Comment: You might also consider a structured text file format such as [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json) as a format to save to, as there is [good support](https://json.codeplex.com/) for serializing it and deserializing it, and the format is relatively compact compared to similar formats such as XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a backing class using DataContract decorations with a list of joint objects then load and save them at will...

For Object serialization, I typically use DataContractJsonSerializer in System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.  Here is an example.

```
[DataContract]
class ExampleSaveableClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<ExampleElements> _elements;

    public ExampleSaveableClass()
    {
        _elements = new List<ExampleElements>();
    }



    internal static ExampleSaveableClass FromJsonString(string jsonString)
    {
        ExampleSaveableClass loadedSavableClass = Deserialize<ExampleSaveableClass>(jsonString);
        return loadedSavableClass;
    }

    private static T Deserialize<T>(string json)
    {
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(instance.GetType());
            return (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
        }
    }
    internal string ToJsonString()
    {

        DataContractJsonSerializer ser =
            new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ExampleSaveableClass));
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ser.WriteObject(ms, this);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }

}
```

Then in your app you can...

```
{
    private void ShowExportDialog(ExampleSaveableClass myClass)
    {

        var dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.Title = "Filename and Location to Export Sample Objects";
        dlg.FileName = "MySavedObjects"; // Default file name
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".json"; // Default file extension
        dlg.Filter = "JSON documents (.json)|*.json"; // Filter files by extension

        // Show save file dialog box
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        // Process save file dialog box results
        if (result == true)
        {
            string str = myClass.ToJsonString();
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(dlg.FileName, str, Encoding.UTF8);
        } 


    }

    public static ExampleSaveableClass ImportSavedClass()
    {
        //Pseudo obtain filename...
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.FileName = "Event"; // Default file name
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".json"; // Default file extension
        dlg.Filter = "JSON documents (.json)|*.json"; // Filter files by extension

        // Show open file dialog box
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        // Process open file dialog box results
        if (result != true)
        {
           return null;
        }

        string filename = dlg.filename;
        ExampleSaveableClass loadedSaveableClass = null;
        FileStream fs = null;
        try
        {
            fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
            var ds = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ExampleSaveableClass));
            loadedSaveableClass = (ExampleSaveableClass)ds.ReadObject(fs);
        }
        finally
        {
            if(null != fs)
            {
                fs.Close();
            }
        }
        return loadedSaveableClass;
    }
}
```